# accessing params passed into update_attribute/create in before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

have model

```
Class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apples
  before_save :include_prime_apple_in_apples
  has_one :prime_apple


 def include_prime_apple_in_apples
     self.apple_ids << prime_apple_1.id
 end
end

l=ModelA.new(:apple_ids => [ "ap_1_id", "ap_2_id"],:prime_apple => prime_apple_1)
l.save
l.apple_ids.should include(prime_apple_1.id) # this doesnt seem to work
```

How change the params passed for associations?

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong there but to answer your question:
AFAIK you can only assign to "other_ids". Also you can push directly to the has_many relation:

```
self.apple_ids = self.apple_ids + [prime_apple_1.id]
```

or

```
self.apples << prime_apple_1
```

Do you have different foreign_key set in the Apple model?
has many will do a select * from apples where modela_id = X
has one will do a select * from apples where modela_id = X limit 1
Which means that whatever you'll set on the prime_apple accessor you'll get back the first Apple record ...